typescript error when inner function is called with conditional optional param
I have a function useIsItemOnPlan that get an item: Item as param. This function should return a function with params that are based on the parent (useIsItemOnPlan) param (based on if the parent params extends CountableItem or NotCountableItem). Until here it is OK.
The problem is when the inner (anonymous) function try to call another, third, function (getIsItemOnPlan) that its params involve both the first function param and the second function param, where the second param is optional. It raises typescript error that I don't know how to solve. can you help?
I already got explanation on the comment how to solve it for func2 and I just added another issue - funct3. thank you
type Item = 'water' | 'cake' | 'box' | 'banana';
type CountableItem = Exclude<Item, 'water'>
type NotCountableItem = Extract<Item, 'water'>

type Params = { [K in Item]: K extends CountableItem ? { quantity: number } : undefined }

function useIsItemOnPlan<K extends Item>(item: K) {
  const myFunc = (arg: Params[K]) => {
    // the param of this function is: if item is of type CountableItem than {quantity: number}, otherwise - nothing

    //do some stuff
    // then return the answer from another function:
    return getIsItemOnPlan(item, arg);
  }



  type MyFunc2Param = { onYes?: () => unknown; requirements: Params[K] }


  const myFunc2 = (params: MyFunc2Param) => {
   func3(requirements? {item, requirements} : {item})
  };
}

function getIsItemOnPlan<K extends Item>(t: K, ...args: [Params[K]] | (Params[K] extends undefined ? [] : never)) {
  const [featureName, requirements] = [t, ...args];

  return true; //do some calcultion and return true or false
}

getIsItemOnPlan("water")


type MyRequest= { item: CountableItem, requirements: {quantity: number }} | {item: NotCountableItem};

function func3(request: MyRequest)  {
  console.log(request)
}
}

playground

what's the typescript error?

its saying item could be water which is not in CountableItem

yes, but I would expect that it will know that (item, ...args) is OK - it is (item: NotCountableItem) or (item: CountableItem, { quantity: number }) which is what getIsItemOnPlan expect. the args is [] if the item is NotCountableItem

in your sample getIsItemOnPlan doesn't support NotCountableItem

@DanielA.White why not?
  ...args: T extends CountableItem ? [T, { quantity: number }] : [T]
if it is CountableItem, the args is [T, { quantity: number }], otherwise (NotCountableItem), the args is [T]
where T is Item

TS can't perform arbitrary analysis of generic types; it tends to defer evaluation of such types until the generic type parameters are instantiated.  So the type [T, ...T extends U ? X : Y] and the type T extends U ? [T, ...X] : [T, ...Y] will likely be identical, but if T is generic TS doesn't spend any effort trying to understand that. So you'll either need type assertions, or refactoring so that TS doesn't need to analyze it, such as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what's missing?

@jcalz thanks! your solution works. I just still don't understand why

@jcalz, i took your playground link (which solved my issue) and I tried to do another similar thing and it is not work (see the call to myFunc) - can yo help me to fix it please?
bit.ly/3KxDYkR

I might look at a followup problem after we get this question taken care of; are you saying I should write up an answer here and you'll accept it? Or is this new issue somehow preventing that?

those are similar issue. i would love to get an explaintion for both of them. I will update my question with the second playground too

I'd try to write your code so that it explicitly writes all the types the same and doesn't try to require TS understand generic conditional parameter list lengths, as shown in this playground link.  Your two scenarios are similar but not the same; please choose one of them to make the question about and [edit] to remove the other one. If it turns out to be the second one, make sure your plaintext code agrees with it.

@jcalz thanks you really helped me. can I have 1 more related?
if I want to create a new function:
type MyRequest= { item: CountableItem, requirements: {quantity: number }} | {item: NotCountableItem};
function func3(request: MyRequest)  {console.log(request)}.
an I want to call it from the myFunc2. how can I do it correctly?
something like:
const myFunc2 = (params: MyFunc2Param) => {func3(requirements? {item, requirements} : {item})}

@jcalz I just edited my question. I now see that in your solution is now required to send "requirements" also for uncountable items and i don't want it.. if the item is water, you shouldn't have to send this because this is always undefined

"can I have 1 more related?" I'm confused by the way this comment chain is going; I'm trying to clarify the original question but it seems like we keep expanding or changing the scope of the question. Please [edit] to make this a single well-defined question that isn't a moving target. It should be getting narrower, if anything.  I don't intend to look at the new version of the code because I'm worried that, if I do that, we'll get func4 and func5 and this will never end. I will disengage now unless I see a more amenable [edit].
